# Tool bars in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have created the tool bars, i can pick it as a separate frame bar (as a floating window) and also i can close it. But i couldn't bring this again. if it so i need to re execute the application then only it will show... otherwise how can i bring this frame bar again?.

PB Version 10. Build 7516

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for my question..

Parentwindow.toolbarvisible = true